# Monero does not connect

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I downloaded the latest version of the monero gui. I have some monero on my ledger nano x and the installation and the connection with the ledger works fine.

The Daemon failed to start and the gui could not connect to the internet. I think it is a problem with the firewall, so I add monerod and monero-wallet-gui to the exceptions for windows defender in windows 10.

But nothing happens and after 120 seconds I again got the following message:

[01.01.2021 13:05] 2021-01-01 12:05:44.285 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.8-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

GUI version: 0.17.1.8-8e6a2cde (Qt 5.9.9)
Embedded Monero version: 0.17.1.8-release
Wallet path: C:\Users\user\Documents\Monero\wallets\Thomas Hoppe\Thomas Hoppe
Wallet restore height: 2244496
Wallet log path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\monero-wallet-gui\monero-wallet-gui.log
Wallet mode: Simple modeOpenGL

Would be really nice, if the community could help. Thanks in advance;=)

Thomas

Comment: Additionaly I have now set an exception in Windows Defender for the whole folder, where monero is installed. But nothing happens and noc connection could be established. When I start monerod.exe manually a short black Windows appears and disappears at once...

Thomas

Comment: Can you check the guide I linked?